# Is it possible to load data into mongodb from a javascript file? If so how?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am following a slightly older tutorial which requires one to load a javascript file into a mongo database using the following command.

```
babel-node loadTestData.js
```

That resulted in the following:

> You have mistakenly installed the `babel` package, which is a no-op in
>   Babel 6.
>
> Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the `babel` package to the
>   `babel-cli` package.

```
npm uninstall babel
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

See http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ for setup instructions.

I tried `./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js  loadTestData.js` but no cigar. Instead I got this error.

```
url.js:88
throw new TypeError('Parameter "url" must be a string, not ' + typeof url);
^

TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined
    at Url.parse (url.js:88:11)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:82:5)
    at module.exports (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/my-fullstack-javascript-app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:16:23)
    at connect (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/my-fullstack-javascript-app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:486:16)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/my-fullstack-javascript-app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:250:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/my-fullstack-javascript-app/loadTestData.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/my-fullstack-javascript-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/my-fullstack-javascript-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

This is the file:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import assert from 'assert';
import config from './config';

MongoClient.connect(config.mongodbUri, (err, db) => {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  db
    .collection('contests')
    .insertMany([
      {
        id: 1,
        categoryName: 'Business/Company',
        contestName: 'Cognitive Building Bricks',
        description: `
This product is a classroom tool that scaffolds higher order thinking. Its a collaborative strategy that using building bricks to help structure students ideas. Learners build knowledge structures with information (attached to different coloured bricks). Students desks are turned into workshops where they physically manipulate information into meaningful creations. They show sequences of information (like stories), rank information by importance and pretty much all other essential cognitive skills you need at school. The end result is clarity in thought and better collaborative conversations. I want this to be marketed as a sophisticated knowledge tool applicable to all ages and subjects. It gives students the cognitive edge, they get a little more 'RAM'!.

I want to continue with the construction/building theme as well as the mind/brain/learning theme. They need to be blended somehow. Teachers find it easier to talk about building/scaffolding analogies as its less abstract.
      `,
        nameIds: [101, 102]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        categoryName: 'Magazine/Newsletter',
        contestName: 'Educating people about sustainable food production',
        description: `
Educating people about sustainable food production
      `,
        nameIds: []
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        categoryName: 'Software Component',
        contestName: 'Big Data Analytics for Cash Circulation',
        description: `
Data is created at every touch point in a notes life-cycle. Because of the volume of the data, it can be difficult to store, analyse and gain insight. Collecting, processing and analysing the data using big data technologies and displaying the results in an interactive display makes it easy to make informative decisions, overcome problem and plan for the future.

It works using big data technologies and displays the results in modern browsers, combining powerful visualisation components and a data-driven approach to interact with the data.

It enables you to analyse data that were not previously possible. The volume, variety, complexity of the analytical processing involved, and the responsiveness required are now achievable with the product. Gaining smarter decision making but also provide faster time to value.
    `,
        nameIds: [103, 104, 105]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        categoryName: 'Website',
        contestName: 'Free programming books',
        description: `
A list of free online programming books, categorized by languages/topics
    `,
        nameIds: []
      }
    ])
    .then(response => {
      console.info('Contests', response.insertedCount);
      db
        .collection('names')
        .insertMany([
          { id: 101, name: 'Mind Assembly', timestamp: new Date() },
          { id: 102, name: 'Brain Scaffold', timestamp: new Date() },
          { id: 103, name: 'Cash View', timestamp: new Date() },
          { id: 104, name: 'Currency Map', timestamp: new Date() },
          { id: 105, name: 'Cash Board', timestamp: new Date() },
          { id: 106, name: 'RootLib', timestamp: new Date() }
        ])
        .then(response => {
          console.info('Names', response.insertedCount);
          db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

The instructor got it to work because he then goes into the mongo shell and gets this command to work:

```
`db.contests.count()` // returns 4
```

Can this be done?

**UPDATE**
This is my config...

```
const env = process.env;

const nodeEnv = env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const logStars = function(message) {
  console.info('**********');
  console.info(message);
  console.info('**********');
};

const config = {
  mongodbUri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
  port: env.PORT || 8016,
  host: env.HOST || 'localhost',
  get serverUrl() {
    return 'http://localhost:8016';
  }
};

module.exports = {
  nodeEnv,
  logStars,
  config
};
```

Comment: Do you have a ./config.js file ? If so what does it look like (without the real url and password) ?

Comment: @JulienTASSIN Well this is just for development right now...
But I just updated my question to include my `config.js` file...

Comment: I think that you should turn `import config from './config';` to `import {config } from './config';`

Comment: @JulienTASSIN That was it pal!!

Comment: Glad to help :)